# After ubuntu upgrade to 18.04, my monitor does a refresh like old cathod tube monitor

Tags: drivers, 18.04, video, intel, monitor

I was using Ubuntu 16.04 and it came up the dialog to update to 18.04. It started updating, but apparently it failed at some point, because when i restarted the PC, it failed to boot. I made some recovery and some stuff that i found on internet, and togheter with some partner's help, we managed to start the GUI. The problem is that my LCD monitor is refreshing like an old cathode tube monitor. I think that it's skipping frames. It's impossible to watch a YouTube video. Maybe it's rendering the screen using software, not hardware? I took a look on the possible resolution and refreshrate configurations using `xrand -q` and i got this:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1600 x 900, current 1600 x 900, maximum 1600 x 900
default connected primary 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900      77.00*
```

I have no NVIDIA card. I have the Intel's integrated graphic card. Using `lspci | grep VGA` I get this:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

What can I do?

Thank you for future responses.